# How to export an IDW DTM as a GeoTIFF file in R

Tags: raster, r, dem, lidr, inverse-distance-weighted

I have loaded both `raster` and `lidR` packages within RStudio and I am trying to export the IDW DTM files but have been receiving errors about 'format'. I have exported a TIN DTM already however with IDW it will not seem to work?

```
setwd("C:/Users/niall/OneDrive - Maynooth University/GY641 Aerial Surveys & Drone/LiDAR Assignment/LiDAR Files/Ppointcloud")

las = readLAS("subsubset_ca.las")

dtm_idw <- rasterize_terrain(las, algorithm = knnidw(k = 10L, p = 2))

writeRaster(dtm_idw, filename = "C:/Users/niall/OneDrive - Maynooth University/GY641 Aerial Surveys & Drone/LiDAR Assignment/Lidr/IDW DEM.tif", format = "GTiff")
```

To which I receive the error:

> Error: [write] unknown option(s): format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setwd("C:/Users/niall/OneDrive - Maynooth University/GY641 Aerial Surveys & Drone/LiDAR Assignment/LiDAR Files/Ppointcloud")

las = lidR::readLAS("subsubset_ca.las")

dtm_idw <- lidR::rasterize_terrain(las, algorithm = knnidw(k = 10L, p = 2))

terra::writeRaster(dtm_idw, filename = "C:/Users/niall/OneDrive - Maynooth University/GY641 Aerial Surveys & Drone/LiDAR Assignment/Lidr/IDW DEM.tif")
```

Answer (score 1):

`dtm_idw` is a `SpatRaster` from `terra`. `terra::writeRaster` does not have `format` argument. Load `terra` and remove `format`